# Javascript Methodname is replaced with !==

Tags: browser, javascript

On the server lies a html file with javascript code included. This javascript code includes a method called something like "CheckObject".

This file works for all users, except one specific (but important). He gets a javascript error and in his browser sourcode appears something unbelievable: The methodname "CheckObject" is replaced with "Check!==ect", means the "Obj" of the method name is replaced with !==.

Why could that be?

Comment: More information would be helpful, e.g. what browsers and plugins the successful/unsuccessful users are using.  One possibility: a  GreaseMonkey script in the important user's Firefox is changing the JS (as they do) in a way not intended.

Comment: @CarlF: I agree, this is most likely an issue on the client-side, with some plugin/addin/script messing with the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your encoding. Use [the W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/) for this.